# Configuring EF code first without a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Catalog> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class Catalog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Using Entity Framework code first I configure this using:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // not rules setup yet
}
```

Currently when EF creates my database it creates a nullable foreign key in the Catalogs table called Product_Id. Is there a way to configure EF to not create any foreign key in the Catalog table?

The catalog table contains imported items from a catalog that should have no relation to the Products table. At run time a search query will be fired for each product and the result will be added to the catalog collection of the product object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose I would exclude the `Matches` collection from the model, either by data annotation...

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Catalog> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

...or in Fluent code:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
             .Ignore(p => p.Matches);
```